# How to align text and button like this,bootstrap

Tags: html, css

How to align text button to the left side and to the right side with bootstrap , here is screen and code , maybe question is stupid but I am just a beginner in this field.
How i could make it , I will be awesome if bg image will be responsive on mobile after theese changes.

```css
.graphics {
 background: url("img/graphics.png");  /* projektowanie grafiki block */
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: Lato;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 100px 0px;
}


.btn-primary {
 background-color:#090045;
 margin-right:350px;
 border-radius: 0;
 border-width: thin;
}
```

```html
  <div class = "graphics">
<h2>Projektowanie graficzne</h2>
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#projektowanie-graficzne">Zobacz więcej</a>
</div>
```

How it looks now
https://ibb.co/Brz8S4K

How it should looks
https://ibb.co/tm4HCdf

Answer (score 0):

`a` elements are inline-elements. That means they do not start on a new line.

Just add `display:block`  to the `a` element. And maybe remove the margin-right so it will stay on the right side.

OR to make it on a new line but keep it's width you can wrap all your text inside a `p` element which is block. So a will go on a new line without having to add anything to it.

[inline/block elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

```css
.graphics {
 background: url("img/graphics.png");  /* projektowanie grafiki block */
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: Lato;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 100px 0px;
  background-color: black
}


.btn-primary {
 background-color:red;
 /* margin-right:350px; maybe remove this */
 border-radius: 0;
 border-width: thin;

}
```

```html
<div class = "graphics">
<h2>Projektowanie graficzne</h2>
<p>
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#projektowanie-graficzne">Zobacz więcej</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a `<p>` element and also add `mr-auto` on button to right align it to the text.

```css
.graphics {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
  /* projektowanie grafiki block */
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 100px 0px;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #090045;
  margin-right: 350px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="graphics">
    <h2>Projektowanie graficzne</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem
      ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem
      ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem
      ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsumipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
    </p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md mr-auto" href="#projektowanie-graficzne">Zobacz więcej</a>
  </div>
</div>
```